# Comparing objects using Jasmine Specs

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, specs

Hey so I was playing around with Jasmine today and I wrote this simple Person object

```
function Person() {}
Person.prototype.name = "Alex";
Person.prototype.age = 24;
```

Here's my Spec test

```
describe("Person", function() { 
var someone = new Person();
it('should be equal to other people', function() {
var another = {
name: "Joe",
age: 25,
};
expect(someone).toEqual(another);
});
});
```

Yet it fails with Expected {  } to equal { name : 'Alex', age : 24 }
Shouldn't Jasmine's toEqual matcher work for objects? Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you walk through the source code, you will see that Jasmine's `toEqual` matcher ultimately uses `hasOwnProperty` when comparing objects.  You can see this in this snippet of code in [matchersUtil.js](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/matchers/matchersUtil.js).

```
function has(obj, key) {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(key);
}
```

*That* function is used in the [`eq` function](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/matchers/matchersUtil.js#L53) in the same file [in this way](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/matchers/matchersUtil.js#L150):

```
  // Deep compare objects.
  for (var key in a) {
    if (has(a, key)) {
      // Count the expected number of properties.
      size++;
      // Deep compare each member.
      if (!(result = has(b, key) && eq(a[key], b[key], aStack, bStack, customTesters))) { break; }
    }
  }
```

...*annnnd* the `eq` function is used by `toEqual.js` matcher when `util.equals` is called.

So, because the `toEqual` matcher uses `hasOwnProperty`, when it does a comparison it will not "see" properties up the prototype chain but only properties on the immediate object.

**One note**: using your code, I got a slightly but significantly different result for the test:

`Expected { } to equal {name: 'Joe', age:  25 }`

That lines up with Jasmine's usage of `hasOwnProperty` making `someone` appear empty when prototype properties are ignored.